# Spark job hangingup in EC2 m4.10x machine

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below code that launches a spark job, when I am working on files less than 40 (maximum cores in my machine) the parallelize works fine, however when I work on files more than that its creating trouble. Any advise please.
`

```
object Cleanup extends Processor {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fileSeeker = new TelemetryFileSeeker("Config")
    val files = fileSeeker.searchFiles(bucketName, urlPrefix, "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "2018-04-30T00:00:00.000Z").filter(_.endsWith(".gz"))
      .map(each => (each, each.slice(0, each.lastIndexOf("/")))).slice(0,100)
    if (files.nonEmpty) {
      println("Number of Files" + files.length)
      sc.parallelize(files).map(each => changeFormat(each)).collect()
    }
  }

  def changeFormat(file: (String, String)): Unit = {
    val fileProcessor = new Processor("Config", sparksession)
    val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
    val tempInput = "inputfolder" + uuid
    val tempOutput = "outputfolder" + uuid

    val inpaths = Paths.get(tempInput)
    val outpaths = Paths.get(tempOutput)
    if (Files.notExists(inpaths)) Files.createDirectory(inpaths)
    if (Files.notExists(outpaths)) Files.createDirectory(outpaths)
    val downloadedFiles = fileProcessor.downloadAndUnzip(bucketName, List(file._1), tempInput)
    val parsedFiles = fileProcessor.parseCSV(downloadedFiles)
    parsedFiles.select(
      "pa1",
      "pa2",
      "pa3"
    ).withColumn("pa4", lit(0.0)).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format(CSV_FORMAT)
      .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save(tempOutput)

    val processedFiles = new File(tempOutput).listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".gz"))
    val filesNames = processedFiles.map(_.getName).toList
    val filesPaths = processedFiles.map(_.getPath).toList

    fileProcessor.cleanUpRemote(bucketName, "new/" + file._2, filesNames)
    fileProcessor.uploadFiles(bucketName, "new/" + file._2, filesPaths)
    fileProcessor.cleanUpLocal(tempInput, tempOutput)

    val remoteFiles = fileProcessor.checkRemote(bucketName, "new/" + file._2, filesNames)
    logger.info("completed " + file._1)
  }
}
```

spark config below

```
lazy val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Project")
.config("spark.master", "local[*]")
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
.config("spark.executor.memory", "5g")
.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
```

FYI: each function parsecsv function downloads 1 file into temporary folder and creates a dataframe in the specific folder. Files are of size 1GB. Also, I am trying to run this using java -cp jar class.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't figure out the exact issue I tried to bypass the issue by passing only 38 files at a time by using the "List->grouped" method